# SignalR Hub sending message but no clients receive it

Tags: quartz.net, asp.net-core-signalr, mediatr

I have a aspnetcore Mvc website which is running a QuartzNet Scheduler.
The Scheduler has listeners which are triggered when a Job is executing and has been executed. The listener is using MediatR to publish a message which is then being handled by a class called JobListenerEventsDispatcher.

This class has the IServiceProvider injected in the constructor in order to get the SignalR hub.

The server side is running aspnetcore 2.2
Both the QuartzScheduler and MediatR are the latest version.

Code from Startup ConfigureServices adding the MediatR service to the ServiceCollection:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

Code in the QuartzNet JobListener publishing the MediatR message:

```
private async Task SendJobMessage(IJobExecutionContext model,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        await _service.Publish(new JobListenerEvent { JobContext = model }, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         // ignored
    }
}
```

Code in the dispatcher receiving the message from the JobListener:

```
public async Task Handle(JobListenerEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var context = _services.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<SchedulerHub>>();
    await context.Clients.All.SendAsync("jobMessage", notification, cancellationToken);
}
```

Sofar it is working perfectly and the Handle method is sending the message to the clients.

JavaScript code adding SignalR and subscribing to the message from the hub:

```
    // SignalR actions
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('/scheduler-hub')
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.None)
        .build();

    connection.on('jobMessage', function (model) {
        logToConsole("jobMessage", model);
        loadCurrentExecutingJobs();
    });
```

The connection is established but the jobMessage handler is not receving anything the server side.

Has anyone else managed to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.
I had my Joblistener interact with a api controller.
The controller got the hubcontext via constructor injection and sent the msg..